# C Compiling Error on different gcc environment

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, compiler-errors

My C program compiles fine on Ubuntu gcc but on Solari there is a error:

```
gcc dhtserver.o map.o -o dhtserver -Wall
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
bind                                dhtserver.o
getsockname                         dhtserver.o
accept                              dhtserver.o
listen                              dhtserver.o
gethostbyname                       dhtserver.o
sendto                              dhtserver.o
socket                              dhtserver.o
connect                             dhtserver.o
recvfrom                            dhtserver.o
inet_pton                           dhtserver.o
inet_ntop                           dhtserver.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to dhtserver
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is there symbol referencing error? 
Solari gcc version:4.2.1 Ubuntu:4.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solaris is (was?) SYSV. Traditionally, this wants to have the socket libraries explicitely mentioned to the linker. Try linking with: `-lsocket -lnsl`.

Comment: @YeminYu: Typically the man page for a function will tell you what headers you need to `#include` and what `-l` options you need to use it. For example, `man getsockname` on Solaris 9 says to use `-lsocket -lnsl`.